# pass php variale to 3d flipbook shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, wordpress-shortcode

**Environment**

```
Wordpress 6.2.2
php 8.0.26
wampserver 3.3.0
```

**Code Source**

```
[Javapoint Example 1][1]
```

**My Code**

```
<! Doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
 <meta charset="utf-8">  
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">  
<title> PHP Select Dropdown Example </title>  
<style>  
 .container {  
  max-width: 400px;  
  margin: 60px auto;  
  text-align: center;  
}  
input[type="submit"] {  
  margin-bottom: 25px;  
}  
.select-block {  
  width: 350px;  
  margin: 100px auto 40px;  
  position: relative;  
}  
select {  
  width: 100%;  
  height: 50px;  
  font-size: 100%;  
  font-weight: bold;  
  cursor: pointer;  
  border-radius: 0;  
  background-color: #1A33FF;  
  border: none;  
  border: 2px solid #1A33FF;  
  border-radius: 4px;  
  color: white;  
  appearance: none;  
  padding: 8px 38px 10px 18px;  
  -webkit-appearance: none;  
  -moz-appearance: none;  
  transition: color 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, border-bottom-color 0.3s ease;  
}  
  select::-ms-expand {  
  display: none;  
}  
.selectIcon {  
  top: 7px;  
  right: 15px;  
  width: 30px;  
  height: 36px;  
  padding-left: 5px;  
  pointer-events: none;  
  position: absolute;  
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, border-color 0.3s ease;  
}  
.selectIcon svg.icon {  
  transition: fill 0.3s ease;  
  fill: white;  
}  
select:hover {  
  color: #000000;  
  background-color: white;  
}  
select:focus {  
  color: #000000;  
  background-color: white;  
}  
select:hover~.selectIcon  
 {  
  background-color: white;  
}  
select:focus~.selectIcon {  
  background-color: white;  
}  
select:hover~.selectIcon svg.icon  
{  
  fill: #1A33FF;  
}  
select:focus~.selectIcon svg.icon {  
  fill: #1A33FF;  
}  
h2 {  
 font-style: italic;  
 font-family: "Playfair Display","Bookman",serif;  
 color: #999;   
 letter-spacing: -0.005em;   
 word-spacing:1px;  
 font-size: 1.75em;  
 font-weight: bold;  
}  
h1 {  
 font-style: italic;  
 font-family: "Playfair Display","Bookman",serif;  
 color: #999;   
 letter-spacing: -0.005em;   
 word-spacing: 1px;  
 font-size: 2.75em;  
 font-weight: bold;  
}  
input[type=submit] {  
 border: 3px solid;  
 border-radius: 2px;  
 color: ;  
 display: block;  
 font-size: 1em;  
 font-weight: bold;  
 margin: 1em auto;  
 padding: 1em 4em;  
 position: relative;  
 text-transform: uppercase;  
}  
 input[type=submit]::before,  
 input[type=submit]::after {  
 background: #fff;  
 content: '';  
 position: absolute;  
 z-index: -1;  
}  
input[type=submit]:hover {  
color: #1A33FF;  
}  
</style>  
</head>  
 <body>  
  <div class="container mt-5">  
   <h1> Select a Book</h1>  
    <form action="" method="post">  
    <select name="bookselect">  
    <option value = "" selected> Select option </option>  
    <option value = "10" > book-July </option>  
    <option value = "16" > book-August </option>  
    <option value = "17" > book-September </option>  
    <option value = "18" > book-October </option>  
    <option value = "19" > book-November </option>
    <option value = "20" > book-December </option>      
  </select>  
  <div class="selectIcon">  
    <svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 104 128" width="25" height="35" class="icon">  
      <path  
        d="m2e1 95a9 9 0 0 1 -9 9 9 9 0 0 1 -9 -9 9 9 0 0 1 9 -9 9 9 0 0 1 9 9zm0-3e1a9 9 0 0 1 -9 9 9 9 0 0 1 -9 -9 9 9 0 0 1 9 -9 9 9 0 0 1 9 9zm0-3e1a9 9 0 0 1 -9 9 9 9 0 0 1 -9 -9 9 9 0 0 1 9 -9 9 9 0 0 1 9 9zm14 55h68v1e1h-68zm0-3e1h68v1e1h-68zm0-3e1h68v1e1h-68z">  
      </path>  
    </svg>  
  </div>  
  <br> <br> <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Select Book">  
</form>  
<?php  
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
    if(!empty($_POST['bookselect'])) {  
        $selected = $_POST['bookselect'];  
        echo 'You have chosen: ' . $selected;
        $flipbook_popup = '[3d-flip-book id="'.$selected.'" ][/3d-flip-book]';
        echo do_shortcode($flipbook_popup);
    } else {  
        echo 'Please select the book.';  
    }  
    }  
  ?>
  </div>  
  </body>  
  </html>
```

**Problem**
I am trying to use this code in a HTML block in a Page. Upon opening the page in a preview, the selection is showing all items and after selecting and clicking submit, it is not showing any of the echo result. Even the selected is not showing on screen. The tab just waits for few seconds after clicking submit and refreshes.

Can any one help?

Moved the php part to a bookselect.php and made the dropdown action to the php file

```
<form action="bookselect.php" method="post">
```

Now the echo commands are working but the echo do_shortcode is simply showing the shortcode only, but not executing the shortcode.

```
[3d-flip-book id="20" ][/3d-flip-book]
```

Comment: I would assume that a feature called "HTML Block" is probably meant to insert HTML - but _not_ to execute contained PHP code ...? (Plus, it is surely meant to insert content into the _body_ inside of the existing page template, and not to insert another _full_ HTML document.)

Comment: My current problem is on how do I execute a shortcode based on the selection. I was able to put the php code in a php file and changed the action to the php file. However, the shortcake is not getting executed.

Comment: An arbitrary PHP file, that has no connection to WP? Then it won't know the `do_shortcode` function in there. You can try if it works if you include the `wp-load.php` file, not sure if that will be enough though. Ideally this would be placed somewhere "in" WordPress, instead of trying to hack it in via some "HTML block" or "eval PHP code" snippet ...

Comment: Is there any Wordpress cookbook on how to get the do_shortcode work? I have tried to read and understand Wordpress help files, but unable to follow.

Comment: It does automatically work, if your PHP code runs "within" the whole WP environment, but not if you just put it into a stand-alone script file, that has no real connection to the WP code base. To put the form and the PHP code into a custom page template, and then assign that template to a page (and leave the form action empty, so that it automatically targets the same URL again), should for example work.

Comment: Seems too much for my level of coding. If you don't mind, can you pl help. I'm using a basic theme Twenty twenty Three of Wordpress. Thanks

Comment: @cbroe, I have made the suggestions made by you. Created a template within the theme, and assigned it to the page. Tested with code in page as well as template, the result is still displaying "[3d-flip-book id="20" ][/3d-flip-book]". The only change is that the selection is being passed to the shortcode string. Execution of do_shortcode is not occurring. It just echoes.

Comment: That is really weird, I have no explanation for that; other, than that whatever adds this shortcode functionality, has for some reason not loaded already at this point ...?